# Communication through LAN in Java without Client

Tags: java

just a quick question: I'm currently trying to write a program that is supposed to capture data from a device that's connected to our Local Area Network and then store it in the database. The problem is that I can't install Java in said device (ZK Software X628C, a fingerprint reader to confirm access of an employee). I just have to send a short command and then get back the data.

Is it possible to implement something like this with Java? Everything I found was always communication between Server/Client both written in Java.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: It doesn't matter what language or system you use for two communication partners, as long as they both follow a specific protocol. Just look at all the different IRC clients, bittorrent clients, and so on. As long as the protocol is specified and followed, any language capable of network communication can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this device communicates through the **network**, that gives a good hint that such communication is independent of Java. It most probably uses some network standards. Java however is a good choice for writing software to communicate through the network with this device, since it has a lot of networking functions already implemented.

I see the manufacturer mentions an SDK (Software Development Kit) being available for this device, so this at least tells one that information about how to communicate with this device *should* be generally available. If the SDK is not available in Java, this might entail a little bit more (low level, technical) work by the software developer, but in general it should be possible **if all necessary information is available**.

Perhaps you should start off by contacting the manufacturer to find out about the SDK and what other information for software developers they have available?

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm downloading the SDK right now and just hope it's for Java.